# What is the Absorbing element under addition on the extended real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, infinity

An Absorbing element is defined as a special type of element of a set with respect to a binary operation on that set. The result of combining an absorbing element with any element of the set is the absorbing element itself. It comes from generalizing the zero under multiplication. [absorbing element wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element)

An absorbing element is unique by its properties so my question is on the extended real number line under addition which do we consider the absorbing element $\infty$ or $-\infty$? or does this set not have an absorbing element under this operation?

Comment: There is no real number $x$ such that $x+y=x \;\forall y$.  Multiplication, however, admits $0$ as an absorbing element as $0\times y=0\;\forall y$.

Comment: thats why i said extended reals it includes infinities. @lulu

Comment: ok, but what is your definition?  Are you including two points, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$?  If so, what do they add to?  If you just add one point and define $\infty+y=\infty\;\forall y\in \mathbb R\cup \infty$ then, sure.

Comment: Just to say, if you are following the conventions of, say, [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) then $\infty +(-\infty)$ is not defined, so you haven't got a binary operation.

Comment: What if we projectively extend the Real numbers, i.e. unify positive and negative infinity as a single value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by $\mathbb R\cup \infty$.  If, as makes some sense, you define $x+\infty=\infty\;\forall x\in \mathbb R \cup \infty$, then (tautologically) $\infty$ is absorbing.

Comment: does division have a absorbing element on the real projective extended line? sorry @lulu

Comment: What do you mean by a fixed point?  I think, as a rule, that all questions of this form are easily answered if you give clear and complete definitions.  They seem subtle only because the definitions are unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An absorbing element is unique in a semigroup. The problem is that the extended real numbers do not form a semigroup under addition, as explicitly stated in the Wikipedia entry [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). The structure you have is that of a partial semigroup: $a + (b + c)$ and $(a + b) + c$ are either equal or both undefined. But in such a partial structure, you may have several absorbing elements and indeed, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are both absorbing elements.

Answer (score 0):

If $+\infty$ is an absorbing element under addition in the extended real line, $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, then adding $+\infty$ to any element in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ should give $+\infty$.  But $-\infty\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $(+\infty)+(-\infty)\neq(+\infty)$.